# Web midi API and multiple simultaneous notes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, midi

I am discovering right now the web midi API with a connected USB piano.
Following [this guide](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/03/web-midi-api/) (and reading [the documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/webmidi/)) I understand that you can assign a function to the event "onmidimessage".

My problem is that this function is called for every pressed/released single note, so how should I deal with multiple notes pressed at the same time, with the purpose of playing a chord?

Comment: MIDI is a serial protocol (and a very old one too). Even if you don't actually hear it since the time difference is so small, the notes of a chord are still triggered *after each other*  (serially, so in the original MIDI cables notes would be transmitted one by one...)...

Comment: What's your specific issue in playing a chord? What happens?

Comment: I am trying the ToneJS library which has a polyphonic synthesizer. The triggerattack method accept an array of notes, that I can provide only if I add some grouping logic and consequent latency. https://tonejs.github.io/docs/r12/PolySynth#triggerattack

Comment: The noteon and noteoff MIDI events *are* sent seperately for each note in MIDI, also if they are the notes of a chord and supposed to be played simultaneously

Comment: So from your point I understand that I won't be able to provide an array with more than one note... but it won't be a problem, because the same function is called very quickly. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

For chords, API sends notes one by one with zero delay.

Just start sound without delays.
See example at https://surikov.github.io/webaudiofont/examples/midikey.html

Answer (score -1):

You will need to look at the [`MIDIMessageEvent`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webmidi/#idl-def-MIDIMessageEvent)'s `receivedTime` attribute and group the events by whichever granularity is appropriate for your application to figure out what constitutes a chord. Also, you'll get MIDI events for the keys being released.

The reason I'm saying "whichever granularity is appropriate for your application" is this:

Consider a keyboard player hitting a chord; it might look like this.

```
    time -------------------->

C   #-----------------------#
E    #---------------------#
G   #-------------------------#
```

Whereas a guitar player strumming a chord (assuming they dampen the strings too) might look like

```
    time -------------------->

C   #-----------------------#
E        #-----------------#
G               #-----------#
```

on the same timescale.